# React-Bootstrap: Modal in DOM but not Displaying Properly on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a modal child called from a parent component via a button, the modal is viewed in the DOM, and appears to run on the page, however, it is not showing.

Here is the code to both the parent and the child:

Parent:
[image]

[image]

Child:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBmnD.png)
[image]

Preview (Safari):
[image: Modal in DOM but not displaying.]

The Parent component can be found here:

https://github.com/fritz-c/react-sortable-tree

Comment: You should post the code as text instead of as images. Nobody wants to retype code to help replicate and solve your issue. StackOverflow has great support for code formatting.

Comment: My bad, I thought that would be the case, however I posted the issue on GitHub too, which I believe has kinda bad code formatting while posting issues, so I used the snapshots above and then posted here. I'll take down the pictures and repost them as code when I go home from university.

Answer (score 1):

I did not pay attention the the version of bootstrap I was using. It is stated that react-bootstrap works on bootstrap version 3.3.4 or later, however I think I would stick with 3.3.4 only.